# jQuery click event over jw player on iPad

Tags: jquery, ipad, jwplayer

I currently have jwplayer running on a page.  One of the navigation menus goes on top of the video when clicked.  On a desktop this works fine, even when using the HTML5 player.  If I try it on an iPad however, it doesn't receive click events, in fact they go straight through the menu div and jwplayer registers the clicks.

If I pause the video, all click events work as they should on the menu.

Has anyone ever come up against this before? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue here is that, on iPad, all Touch events occuring in the area of a  element are caught by the video element. This is a well-known limitation of the iOS Safari browser.

Interestingly, this limitation only applies when the iOS controlbar for the video element is enabled. If the controls are disabled, the events are not "stolen" anymore by the video element.

JW Player 6.0 supports an undocumented option called "mobilecontrols" when setting that "true", JW Player will disable the iOS video controls and draw its own, fixing your issue. JW Player is not yet optimized to handle with Touch events though, which is why we don't do this by default yet. You should evaluate for yourself if the behaviour is acceptable (for example, dragging the timeslider has no effect until released).

Comment: Thanks! In this scenario I've actually just opted to pause the video when the menu is clicked but that's great to know.

Comment: I wondered how you would know that, when it is  undocumented. But it's Mr. JW himself ;) Thanks for the help. It seems the jwcontrols arent fully working though. For example: Fullscreen, volumebar, and the scrubbar seems to have slight problems as well.

Answer (score 1):

It looks most probably that navigation menu has an improper css declaration that is overlapping with the Video Player.

Comment: It seems more like a bug, as when the video is paused it starts working again.